# Do LND reserve balances overlap with each other in any way?

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon, channels

LND 0.16.2-beta

I'm looking at the commands `walletbalance` and `listchannels` (which has output similar to `pendingchannels`). I've modified the numbers in these examples.

```
$ ./lncli walletbalance
{
    "total_balance": "1111111",
    "confirmed_balance": "1111111",
    "unconfirmed_balance": "0",
    "locked_balance": "0",
    "reserved_balance_anchor_chan": "44444",
    "account_balance": {
        "default": {
            "confirmed_balance": "1111111",
            "unconfirmed_balance": "0"
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that `walletbalance` returns a field called `reserved_balance_anchor_chan`. The [documentation](https://docs.lightning.engineering/community-resources/glossary) gives this definition:

> Anchor channels include up to two special outputs called anchors which
> are used for timely CPFP fee-bumping of force-closed channels.

But the response from listchannels (which I've shortened in order to save space) includes a separate local reserve amount for each channel.

```
$ ./lncli listchannels
{
    "channels": [
        {
            "active": true,
            "capacity": "1111111",
            "local_balance": "555555",
            "remote_balance": "444444",
            "local_chan_reserve_sat": "11111",
            "remote_chan_reserve_sat": "11111",
            "local_constraints": {
                "chan_reserve_sat": "11111",
            },
            "remote_constraints": {
                "chan_reserve_sat": "11111",
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Notice the `local_chan_reserve_sat` field. So each channel has its own reserve balance and the node also has this anchor channel with its own reserve balance.

Do the local channel reserve balances overlap at all with the anchor channel reserve balance? In other words, if I have local channel reserve balances of 11111, 22222 and 33333, and I also have an anchor channel reserve balance of 55555, then is my total reserve balance 66666 or 122221?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.

If you have `X` value in `local_chan_reserve_sat` (`X=x1+x2+...+Xn` being `n` the number of channels you have opened) and `Y` value in `reserved_balance_anchor_chan`, then the total reserve will be `X+Y`.

`local_chan_reserve_sat` is the value you cannot go under in a channel. Once achieved, you'll never be able to spend from the reserve. The purpose of it is discouraging misbehavior, basically having something to lose so you don't try to spend an old state once you have completely depleted the channel. This funds are **off-chain**.

`reserved_balance_anchor_chan`, on the other hand, are funds reserved for fee bumping in case they're needed (as you mention in your answer). These funds are **on-chain**.